# Why do I only get "Bad Parameter Type" for one section of SQL Query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have used MS Query to pull a SQL query into an Excel report. I then created parameters so that when a variable changes on another page, so does resultant query data. My problem is that I seem to get an error "Bad Parameter Type" only now and then and I can't seem to understand why the parameter works sometimes and other times not.

For example the below query gives me an error ONLY on the second part of the union for parameter **I2.[Project #] = ?.** The first parameter works fine. As you can see I even tried using same coding for both parameters in the hope that will make it work (and it did for a different query).

PLEASE HELP ME UNDERSTAND WHAT I AM DOING WRONG? Apologies my style of SQL, taught myself.

```
SELECT
    I2.Project [Project #],
    P1.DocNum [PO #],
    I1.DocNum [INV/CN #],
    I1.CardName [Supplier],
    CONCAT(DATENAME(MONTH, I1.DocDate), '-', DATENAME(YEAR, I1.DocDate)) [INV Mth & Yr],
    CONCAT(DATENAME(MONTH, I1.DocDueDate), '-', DATENAME(YEAR, I1.DocDueDate)) [DUE Mth & Yr]
FROM 
    OPCH I1
INNER JOIN 
    PCH1 I2 ON I1.DocEntry = I2.DocEntry
INNER JOIN 
    PDN1 G2 ON I2.BaseEntry = G2.DocEntry
            AND I2.BaseLine = G2.LineNum 
INNER JOIN 
    POR1 P2 ON G2.BaseEntry = P2.DocEntry
            AND G2.BaseLine = P2.LineNum 
INNER JOIN 
    OPOR P1 ON P1.DocEntry = P2.DocEntry
WHERE 
    I2.Project = ?
GROUP BY
    I2.LineNum, I1.DocEntry, I1.DocNum, I2.Project,
    P1.DocNum, I1.CardName, I1.DocDate, I1.DocDueDate

UNION ALL

SELECT
    I2.Project [Project #],
    P1.DocNum [PO #],
    I1.DocNum [INV/CN #],
    I1.CardName [Supplier],
    CONCAT(DATENAME(MONTH, I1.DocDate), '-', DATENAME(YEAR, I1.DocDate)) [INV Mth & Yr],
    CONCAT(DATENAME(MONTH, I1.DocDueDate), '-', DATENAME(YEAR, I1.DocDueDate)) [DUE Mth & Yr]
FROM 
    ORPC I1
INNER JOIN 
    RPC1 I2 ON I1.DocEntry = I2.DocEntry
INNER JOIN 
    PCH1 T2 ON T2.DocEntry = I2.BaseEntry
            AND T2.LineNum = I2.BaseLine
INNER JOIN 
    PDN1 G2 ON T2.BaseEntry = G2.DocEntry
            AND T2.BaseLine = G2.LineNum 
INNER JOIN 
    POR1 P2 ON G2.BaseEntry = P2.DocEntry
            AND G2.BaseLine = P2.LineNum 
INNER JOIN 
    OPOR P1 ON P1.DocEntry = P2.DocEntry
WHERE 
    I2.Project = ?
GROUP BY
    I2.LineNum, I1.DocEntry, I1.DocNum, I2.Project,
    P1.DocNum, I1.CardName, I1.DocDate, I1.DocDueDate
```

Comment: Please tag your question properly!!!  Is this for SQL Server or MySQL???

Comment: Make it easy to assist you, simplify the problem! (Remove all stuff not needed to reproduce.)

Comment: You should really have a separate U_BgtAreaCode mapping table.

Comment: Okay will try make simpler. Will try tag better.

Comment: You should really have a separate U_BgtAreaCode mapping table. – jarlh 4 mins ago
 - Thanks for the tip will look into that

Comment: Thanks for removing the Tag.

Comment: What is the datatype of I2.Project  - is it an integer, or a varchar? And what type of data are you using to fill in the parameter - numbers, or letters?

Comment: @codeulike datatype is varchar. I am pointing the parameter to an Excel cell that has the Project code eg: B0500.
Perhaps I should convert to varchar in case it isn't in the correct format? But that doesn't make sense to me as the credit note is pulled from the invoice and no details are changed hence it should be varchar..

Comment: @marc_s - thank you for editing. Looks much better!